# Android export database to internal storage

Tags: android

in my app I'm trying to make option which can export database from `/data/data/com.example.damian.sshconnection/databases/ssh.db` to internal storage `/sdcard` This is my code:

```
private void exportDatabase(){
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.example.damian.sshconnection" +"/databases/ssh.db";
    String backupDBPath = "/sdcard/ssh.db";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And permissions from AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/ssh.db (Permission denied)
```

What more can I do to get acces into storage from app ?

Comment: What android version are you using?

Comment: @deathangel908 Android version 7.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android 6+, besides manifest permission you should ask permission in runtime as well. Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) article;

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
},666); // 666 is any number,to manually identify permission request in onRequestPermissionsResult callback
```